# RadAutocomplete issue in {NS}-Vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to add a RadAutocomplete in my app and can't populate the component; I followed the tuts but typing something in it lead always to "No results found".

I guess that somehow it is not initialized. My component code is lengthier but I made a shorter playground here, [Nativescript playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ePVkfo&v=1).

Can anybody tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Your code has several issues: `SuggestionView` is outside `RadAutoCompleteTextView`, `searchItems` are never initialised / `getInitial()` is never invoked from anywhere, you are not using `TokenModel` etc., Please go through the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/AutoCompleteTextView/getting-started) carefully.

Comment: Thank you Manoj for taking the time to view this; my mistake, I pointed to a previous playground version, corrected now. In my code as it is now on playground the getInitial was called on created; as I understand from some examples in the official repository, the SuggestionView is not mandatory, nevertheless I moved it in the RadAutoCompleteTextView. As for the TokenModel I tried with and without it, same result of "No Result found", In the playground I used the simple variant without TokenModel for simplicity. In the end, still doesn't work..

Comment: Did it again :-( forgot the playground creates a new version on every modifications and that the original link doesn't get updated, here's the correct one https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ePVkfo&v=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had several issues in the initial version: 
- `SuggestionView` was outside RadAutoCompleteTextView
- searchItems are never initialised / getInitial() is never invoked from anywhere 
- You were not using `TokenModel` etc.,

Your [updated version](http://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ePVkfo&v=8) fixed most, but you were still having typos on variable name and missing `TokenModel` implementation. I have [updated](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=ePVkfo&v=9) it for you.

Comment: Thank you, Manoj! It is working now but I confess I am still a bit confused, I get from your changes that the Token mode has to be used. I have tried with Plain before because I understood from docs that we should use Token only to allow multiple selections, I quote ""acceptable values for the displayModes property:

    Plain - When Plain mode is active, only one item can be selected. The selected item is shown as a plain text in the input field.
    Tokens - In Tokens mode the RadAutoCompleteTextView allows multiple selection of suggestions. The selected items are displayed as tokens.
""

Comment: Can we put objects in the ObervableArray like [ {'name': 'test'} ] . For me I cannot do that but I've seen examples in which it shows that can be done

Comment: You can extend the TokenModel class as show here: https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/autocompletetextview/getting-started#customize-the-tokenmodel